# Avoid escaped characters in Postman responses

Tags: escaping, character, postman

Is there a way to avoid escaped characters in postman responses? I am testing a service where the response come with the following field:

<MethodResult> 
        myurl.com/_/orderclient.php?SessionID=c8e0c826-bfd9-4a7e-95fa-b5602889fd9f**&amp;**OrderID=3518176547**&amp;**Locale=
</MethodResult>

Is there a way to configure postman to not escape characters like & to &amp; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the raw response body in postman in the "raw body tab" (see screenshot below). I do not think you can configure it to always show the raw version. [Within XML documents / tags some characters need to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents), "&" is one of them. This is why I think the escaped version is coming from your web service directly.

[image]

Comment: Raw response also shows the escaped characters. But preview does not escape xml characters. Thanks for the advice, it was usefull.